# Autosys: Concept of Kick Start Attribute and how to use

Tags: automation, autosys

i have a daily( 09:00am) box containing 10 jobs inside it. All child jobs are sequentially scheduled to run.

On Monday, jobs 1,2 &3 completed and job4 failed. And coz of this, the downstream is stalled and the box is running infinetly( until some actions taken manually)

But the requirement is to run this box again on Tue 09:00am. I heard of Kickstart attribute to kick off the box on next scheduled time irrespective of last run status.

Can someone tell about this kick_start attribute? Also suggest me any other way to schedule this box daily.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of the kick_start attribute and could not find it in the R11.3.5 reference guide.

I would look at the box_terminator: y that will fail the box if a job in it fails and the job_terminator: y that will terminate and fail a job if the box it is in fails.

box_criteria is another attribute that may help as you can define what success or failure looks like. For example if you don't care if job4 fails, define box_criteria: s(job3).

Course that only sets your box to FA where it will run the next time it's starting conditions are met. It does nothing to run the downstream for the current run.

Have fun and test, test, test.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bug you, but you might want to chime in here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75325/811